# ctypes.windll.user32.GetCursorInfo() - how can I manage this to work? [Python]

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

I have to get the information about the current mouse cursor from windows but I'm not managing to work this command...

what should I do? 
Can someone post one example?

Comment: Did you make sure to check out the documentation on msdn? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648389%28VS.85%29.aspx) 

Also - post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What information are you trying to get out of the GetCursorInfo() call?  It would be easier to use the [win32 extensions](http://python.net/crew/skippy/win32/Downloads.html) (especially if you just want cursor position).

```
>>> import win32gui
>>> win32gui.GetCursorInfo()
(1, 65555, (717, 412))
```

Comment: I'm trying to get information about the cursor, the type of it... for example, the normal cursor and the cursor for link (the little hand)
edit: it worked... the 65555 number is from the type of the cursor... thx

Comment: win32gui.GetCursorInfo()[1] is the handle to the cursor